# Loop Through 2 Dataframes to Identify Similar Columns for Joins

Tags: r

I have 2 reproducible dataframes over here. I am trying to identify which column contain values that are similar to another column. I hope my code will randomly select 1 value from each column, and loop through every single column in df2.

```
df1 <- data.frame(fruit=c("Apple", "Orange", "Pear"), location = c("Japan", "China", "Nigeria"), price = c(32,53,12))
df2 <- data.frame(grocery = c("Durian", "Apple", "Watermelon"), place=c("Korea", "Japan", "Malaysia"), invoice = c("XD1", "XD2", "XD3"))

df1$source <- "DF1"
df2$source <- "DF2"

df1

   fruit location price source
1  Apple    Japan    32    DF1
2 Orange    China    53    DF1
3   Pear  Nigeria    12    DF1

df2  
     grocery    place invoice source
1     Durian    Korea     XD1    DF2
2      Apple    Japan     XD2    DF2
3 Watermelon Malaysia     XD3    DF2
```

This is the output I hope to obtain under a new dataframe called df3.

```
df3
         grocery    place    invoice source
    1     fruit    location     NA    DF1
```

The source column will allow the user to identify where the respective columns (fruit/location) comes from. The column name of df3 = the column names from df2, whereas the values under row1 = column names from df1.

The column Grocery is matched with fruit as there is a matching value i.e. "Apple" and "Japan" can be found in both place and location columns respectively.

Thank you!

Comment: Not actually clear about your output. Does that mean you will always have only 1 row in output?  Would it always be column names from `df2` as column names for `df3` and column names from `df1` as 1st row?

Comment: Hello Ronak, yes it will only have 1 row. Yes the column name under df3 will always be from df2 and and the row values from df1

Comment: So something like `setNames(data.frame(t(names(df1))), names(df2))` ?

Comment: Nope, it has to loop through the dataframe to identify which columns match up to which, not via a setNames method. You can see that under invoices, it is NA, as the values under invoices cannot be found in df1

Comment: This is clearly doable but you should define "similar values". What do you mean if you say that the values of "grocery" are similar to those in "fruit"? Is one matching value enough? Or two? Or all? Or if one contains "DF1" and "DF2" and the other variable contains "DF3" and "DF4", are they similar?a

Comment: Sounds like two steps. First, find a way to identify like columns and then simply perform a join using `merge` or `left_join`.

Comment: @lebatsnok, yes i think 1 -2 matching values are enough! Nope it should be an exact match

Comment: @hmhensen, yep the purpose of this code is to achieve the identification of like columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the most optimal solution but one way using double `sapply` (since for every column of `df2` we want to find similar columns in `df1`)

```
sapply(names(df2), function(x) {
     temp <- sapply(names(df1), function(y) 
         if(any(match(df2[[x]], df1[[y]], nomatch = FALSE))) y else NA)
     ifelse(all(is.na(temp)), NA, temp[which.max(!is.na(temp))])
   }
)

# grocery     place     invoice     source 
# "fruit" "location"         NA         NA
```

This would give you all the columns in `df2` which `match` atleast in one value with the ones in `df1`. You can then change the `source` column manually later since if there is a row present you know it is from `df1`.

Answer (score 1):

Made a change. It's messy but it works.

```
#create data frame of column combinations
col_combos <- expand.grid(names(df1), names(df2))

#identify like columns
like_cols <- na.omit(col_combos[as.logical(apply(col_combos, 1, function(x) intersect(df1[, x[1] ],df2[, x[2] ]) > 1 )), ])

#match like columns
rbind(names(df2), as.character(like_cols$Var1)[match(names(df2), as.character(like_cols$Var2))])

     [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]    
[1,] "grocery" "place"    "invoice" "source"
[2,] "fruit"   "location" NA        NA
```